# How to parse print-format-style strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

I've noticed that there are several tools that use strings formatted like this (to give a simple arbitrary example):

```
"Hour %h, minute %m, a total of %S seconds have passed"
```

where %(letter) represents a variable. For instance, PHP's "strptime/strftime" command uses %(letter) to represent a component of a date/time. The Git commit log printer takes in an optional format argument where %(letter) refers to a component of a commit (date, author, description, etc).

I'm looking to apply this logic to my own Ruby project. Is there a Ruby library or gem that can parse strings like this?

EDIT: A big thanks to everyone who answered, but what I'm looking for isn't a specialized task like Date.strftime/strptime. My app downloads a set of data from a website and then compiles it into a document, and I want users to be able to choose how that document is formatted. So if I have

```
#<DataObject:0x007fec299de348
@id=123456,
@name="Important data",
@date="1/1/1",
@url="www.url.com">
```

and a user inputs a format string like this:

```
DATA OBJECT %i
%n
Created on %d
See %u for more
```

The result should look like this:

```
DATA OBJECT 123456
Important data
Created on 1/1/1
See www.url.com for more
```

Is there a library that does something general like that, or should I program this logic myself?

EDIT #2: The first comment got it right... a simple substitution would work fine.

Comment: Simple `gsub` should do just fine

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "parse strings like this"? Are you trying to a) Take a formatting string (with `%` in it) and break it apart somehow? b) Take a formatting string and formatted string (with values in place of the `%`) and then extract the values? c) Given an arbitrary formatting string, get a formatted string (replace the `%` placeholders with values)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're right, that would work just fine... Guess I was overthinking this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work with the exact string you have, but with slight modification, you can use the `String#%` method.

```
s = "Hour %{h}, minute %{m}, a total of %{S} seconds have passed"
s % {h: 3, m: 57, S: 24}
# => "Hour 3, minute 57, a total of 24 seconds have passed"
```

Comment: In case I am right, you cannot change it unless it is within five minutes, or someone edits my answer. (But that is not a big problem)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2**: Here's a terse, general solution, based on the edited question:

```
# Replace %foo in format string with value of calling obj.foo
def custom_format(format, obj)
  format.gsub(/%([a-z]\w*)/i){ |s| obj.respond_to?($1) ? obj.send($1) : s }
end

formatter = "DATA OBJECT %id
%name
Created on %date
See %url for more %infoz
We are %pct% done."

# Create a simple class with accessor methods for these attributes
DataObject = Struct.new(:id,:name,:date,:url,:pct)
data = DataObject.new(123456,"Important data","1/1/1","www.url.com",57)

formatted = custom_format(formatter,data)
puts formatted
#=> DATA OBJECT 123456
#=> Important data
#=> Created on 1/1/1
#=> See www.url.com for more %infoz
#=> We are 57% done
```

That regex allows `%x`, `%xyzzy`, and even `%F13` and `%z_x_y`. It allows the user to use literal `%` anywhere, as long as it isn't followed by a known value.

Note that if your object does not have accessor methods, you can instead use:

```
# Replace %foo in format string with value @foo inside obj
# If the value is `nil` or `false` the original placeholder will be used
def custom_format(format, obj)
  format.gsub(/%([a-z]\w*)/i){ |s| obj.instance_variable_get( :"@#{$1}" ) || s }
end
```

…but reaching directly into the object for its instance variables probably isn't the best idea.

---

Given a general or specific *"formatting strings"*:

```ruby
gs = "Hour %d, minute %d"
fs = "Hour %H, minute %M"
```

…you can create a *"formatted string"* by:

- Using [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) or `String#%` with the general string

  ```ruby
  s = sprintf( gs, 1, 2 ) #=> "Hour 1, minute 2"
  s = gs % [1,2]          #=> "Hour 1, minute 2"
  ```
- Using [`Time#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) with a time object (and the correct placeholder values, per the docs):

  ```ruby
  s = Time.now.strftime(fs) #=> "Hour 10, minute 08"
  ```

…you can 'parse' the formatting strings by splitting on `%`:

```ruby
pieces = gs.split(/(%[^%\s])/) #=> ["Hour ", "%d", ", minute ", "%d"]
```

…under most circumstance you can generally extract the values from a *formatted string* using the *formatting string* with this code (only lightly tested):

```ruby
# With s="Hour 10, minute 08"
parts = s.match /\A#{fs.gsub(/%([^%\s])/o,'(?<\1>.+?)')}\z/
p parts[:H] #=> "10"
p parts[:M] #=> "08"

# If the formatting string uses the same placeholder more than once
# you will need to ask for the parts by index, not by name
parts = s.match /\A#{gs.gsub(/%([^%\s])/o,'(?<\1>.+?)')}\z/
p parts[1] #=> "10"
p parts[2] #=> "08"
```

That magic line noise converts the formatting string into a regex that captures and names each placeholder:

```
"Hour %H, minute %M"
/\AHour (?<H>.+?), minute (?<M>.+?)\z/
```

The [`MatchData`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/MatchData.html) returned when you match a string against this regex keeps track of all the parts, both by name and by index.

---

**Edit**: Here's a more robust solution for scanning a string with a formatter, that handles sprintf formatting placeholders such as `%-3d` or `%0.3f`:

```ruby
require 'strscan'
def scan_with_format( format, str )
  s = StringScanner.new(format)
  parts = []
  accum = ""
  until s.eos?
    if (a=s.scan( /%%/ )) || (b=s.scan( /%[^a-z]*[a-z]/i ))
      parts << Regexp.escape(accum) unless accum.empty?
      accum = ""
      parts << (a ? '%' : "(?<#{b[-1]}>.+?)")
    else
      accum << s.getch
    end
  end
  parts << Regexp.escape(accum) unless accum.empty?
  re = /\A#{parts.join}\z/
  str.match(re)
end
```

In action:

```
formatter = "Hour %02d, minute %d, %.3fs $%d and %0d%% done"
formatted = formatter % [1, 2, 3.4567, 8, 90 ]
#=> "Hour 01, minute 2, 3.457s $8 and 90% done"

parts = scan_with_format(formatter, formatted)
#=> #<MatchData "Hour 01, minute 2, 3.457s $8 and 90% done" d:"01" d:"2" f:"3.457" d:"8" d:"90">
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simple and fast way to use `gsub` to dynamically find values in the object in a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) / [DateTime#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime):

```
>> require 'date'
=> false
>> DateTime.strptime("Hour 14, minute 28, a total of 54 seconds have passed", "Hour %H, minute %M, a total of %S seconds have passed")
=> #<DateTime: 2013-07-17T14:28:54+00:00 ((2456491j,52134s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> _.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
=> "14:28:54"
```

Answer (score 1):

For replacing normal strings there's `printf`/[sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
> printf('Hello %s', 'World')
Hello World
```

For a date string look at [Time#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

```
> Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
=> "2013-07-16 23:49:52"
```